# Find out precentage of point x and y between two other points

Tags: java, android, android-maps

In my android app I have simple "map", which is satellite map based image. I have exact `LatLng`positions on two corners of this map: Left-Top and Right-Bottom to be precise. Now, by given `LatLng` point I want to create a small view add place it on the map (a marker). In order to this I have to calculate percentage x and y in pixels on my "map".

So to sum up here's my data:

```
LatLng MAP_LEFT_TOP; //constant point
LatLng MAP_RIGHT_BOTTOM; //constant point
LatLng location; //point, which should be inside map rectangle
```

What I have to calculate:

```
float percentageX; //percentage x position of "location" on the map
float percentageY; //percentage y position of "location" on the map
```

Here I found function:

```
LatLng interpolate(LatLng from, LatLng to, double fraction)
```

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java

and I need something, which works in the opposite way. Here's my implementation, but it doesn't give me correct result (the same for y/longitude):

```
double findFractionX(double latitudeLeftTop, double latitudeRightBottom, double latitude){
    return (latitude - latitudeLeftTop) / (latitudeRightBottom - latitudeLeftTop);
}
```

Then I can get final position of the marker like this:

```
float imageViewWidth; //width of the imageView holding map
float imageViewHeight; //height of the imageView holding map
float x = percentageX * imageViewWidth;
float y = percentageY * imageViewHeight;
```

Edit:
my mistake was using latitude to get x and longitude to get y while it's just the opposite.

Still something's wrong, here's how it looks in the app:

[image]

Here's where it should have been (I used scribble to make this example):

[image]

Just to make it clear I'm talking about point named "1.1", don't pay your attention for the others, they're hardcoded in the image itself.

Comment: Please add how you use your findFractionX function? Because if used correctly, it looks fine to me. Only idea right now is, maybe you switch long/lat and x/y?  Edit: Should add that long = x, lat = y.

Comment: Would still like to know how your call to findFractionX call looks like.  Edit: And where you get your MAP_LEFT_TOP and MAP_RIGHT_BOTTOM from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got another idea to write up, I'll just put both in a full answer to have more space.

First, check if you don't accidentally switched `long`/`lat` or `x`/`y`:

`Long = x` and `lat = y`.

Then, how does you view look that you add? While you get the exact position of the map marker, simply adding a view to that location may look off.

The view itself probably has a width and height itself and you may want it placed on top of the marker like when clicking on a store on Google maps? If you just put it at the calculated position, it will put its top-left corner at that position.

Comment: Yes, I've definitely wrongly assumed that latitude is x and longitude is y. That was an error for sure. Now the point is much closer to the destination, but still off. I consider view size and put it in the center of point (I'm sure that part is correct). Most probably either map is a bit off or the LEFT_TOP/RIGHT_BOTTOM points are inaccurate. I'll edit my answer in a minute and show my results.

Comment: Well, I did provide a solution to his problem, didin't I?

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt Not really; you provided a comment-worthy suggestion. "To have more space" is not a reason to use an answer for comments.

Comment: Fine - I expected the swap to be the solution...or hoped it would be. But I'm still here, and will continue to update this answer when I get anything new to work with. If if you'd like, I'll delete it and make it a comment though, so there isn't any bad blood left lying around.

Comment: Ok - question solved, lat/lon was first mistake and second was graphic's designer providing me inaccurate corner point.

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt Sorry, I wasn't meaning to be an arse about this, and there's always a grey area, but generally, things that "might be" or "are hoped to be" a solution should generally start life in comments and be made an answer if the suspicion is correct.